# add a sheet to an ods file via python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ods

I started with the package simpleodspy

and it worked fine until I wanted to add an new sheet to an ods file.

Than I figured out that simpleodspy is just an better wrapper for odfpy to simpliy the api. So I guess they scipted the adding an sheet part.

So I tried to figure out how to do it with odfpy.

But I stucked.

So does someone know if it is possible to add an sheet to ods files?

If yes how ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the sample code to add a new sheet:

```
from odf.opendocument import load
from odf.table import Table
from odf.table import TableCell
from odf.table import TableRow
from odf.text import P

#loading it
book = load('your.ods')
#create a new sheet in memory
sheet = Table(name="test sheet")
#create a new row
tablerow=TableRow()
#create a new cell
cell=TableCell()
#fill-in a cell
cell.addElement(P(text="hello world"))
#add a cell to the row
tablerow.addElement(cell)
#add the row to the sheet
sheet.addElement(tablerow)
#adding the new to the book
book.spreadsheet.addElement(sheet)
#save it
book.save('your_new.ods')
```